# Starling ImageLoaderCache onComplete

Tags: actionscript-3, air, starling-framework

I am using the image loader cache (http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/imageloader-with-cache-system) class to load an image remotely and save it in cache however I need to apply a mask using PixelMaskDisplayObject to the image and need to wait for it to complete loading however unsure how to apply an oncomplete event listener. The below doesn't fire.

Thanks

```
// Load remote image into cache
this.profileImage = new ImageLoaderCache();
this.profileImage.source = "http://pathtoimage.com/profile.jpg";
this.profileImage.addEventListener(starling.events.Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoadComplete);
```

Comment: you talk about `starling.events.Event.COMPLETE` that `ImageLoaderCache` dispatching?

Comment: please add 'starling-framework' tag

Comment: Correct but adding an event listener on my this.profileImage = new ImageLoaderCache(); results in nothing being fired.

Comment: show how you attaching a listener

Comment: seems to be ok. tried to swap the lines , first attach listener and then assign the source ?

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it could be an issue of the mask being applied.